# add an address search to a custom google map

Tags: google-maps, search, iframe

I am using the new google maps system and an embedded iframe to add my google map into my page with my custom locations.

What I am missing is a way to have a user search their address to see which location is nearest them.

The map lists local Disc Golf courses and I would like to incorporate a search bar that allows you to put in your address so you can see how close you live to the nearest course.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Here is my current iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zgauQ93-BexQ.kryT1881iie4" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Displayed on the site:

http://atxdiscgolf.com/

As you can see... no search bar!  I want to be able to search addresses on this map so I can see how close they are to home!  Please let me know!
Also let me know if you have any Disc Golf courses to add to my list!

Comment: I have created this fiddle to work on this:  http://jsfiddle.net/9sfeqfmg/
this is my "MID" (Map ID)  zgauQ93-BexQ.kryT1881iie4

https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zgauQ93-BexQ.kryT1881iie4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it!

First, I used the "sample code" found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=fr

Then I read about KML layers so...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

I went to My Maps, clicked export as KML, checked to update when my map updates then directed the KML to the file location that I downloaded the KML file from from My Maps.

It worked!  I have a searchable map with my custom overlay embedded!!

It won't let me post more than 2 links so I will post the link to my fiddle in the comments below:

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=fr) in the documentation. It adds a search box to the map, which is what it sounds like you're looking for. If you want to be able to get directions or calculate distances, you may have to use other libraries/apis, though Google Maps v3 does already have a lot of the methods already (like [computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)).

Comment: I am working on a fiddle to embed this however I'm not sure how to add my custom map.  This is my MID:  mid=zgauQ93-BexQ.kryT1881iie4
here is a fiddle I'm working on:  http://jsfiddle.net/9sfeqfmg/  not sure how to add this MID to the embeded map... been reading the API but I'm a bit confused